# ZIndex on Clusters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-groups-api

I am attempting to add custom labels to a map such that the labels are visible on top of the clusters I created using MarkerClusterer. I set the zindex of the labels to 1000. How do I set a zindex on a cluster. I know how to do it with a marker but am not sure how to apply a zindex value to each of my cluster icons. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint. Got it to work myself:
var pane=this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget;

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add your custom labels to a map pane that sits above the clusters.
See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapPanes