# Google Maps: Render marker above markerclusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have a set of markers that get clustered on my map. 
Another set of markers are displayed individually, and i happen to need these to be displayed above the clusters.
I have tried setting zIndex in the clusters options object, lower than that of the 2nd set of markers, but to no avail.
Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330802/zindex-on-clusters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894548/positioning-markers-over-the-top-of-clusters-z-index-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this can't be done. The clusters reside in higher pane than the marker image.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes

Answer (score 5):

It can be done, but it's a pretty bumpy way until you get there... As Rick says, the problem is that the MarkerClusterer adds an own OverlayView with its cluster icons on a higher pane as the regular markers. The only way to add a marker above the clusters is to beat the clusterer with his own weapons and add an own OverlayView and add the marker icon markup to an even higher pane (read about panes [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes)). I don't really like it - but it's the only way I found.

To do this you have to create a custom overlay implementing google.maps.OverlayView ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView)), a good example can be found [here](http://nickjohnson.com/b/google-maps-v3-how-to-quickly-add-many-markers) (with explanations, I used a bit of code from it).

Here is a rough CustomOverlay prototype:

```
// build custom overlay class which implements google.maps.OverlayView
function CustomOverlay(map, latlon, icon, title) {
    this.latlon_ = latlon;
    this.icon_ = icon;
    this.title_ = title;
    this.markerLayer = jQuery('<div />').addClass('overlay');
    this.setMap(map);
};
CustomOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
CustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var $pane = jQuery(this.getPanes().floatPane); // Pane 6, one higher than the marker clusterer
    $pane.append(this.markerLayer);
};
CustomOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){
    this.markerLayer.remove();
};
CustomOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    this.markerLayer.empty(); // Empty any previous rendered markers

    var location = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlon_);
    var $point = jQuery('<div class="map-point" title="'+this.title_+'" style="'
                            +'width:32px; height:32px; '
                            +'left:'+location.x+'px; top:'+location.y+'px; '
                            +'position:absolute; cursor:pointer; '
                        +'">'
                        +'<img src="'+this.icon_+'" style="position: absolute; top: -16px; left: -16px" />'
                    +'</div>');

    fragment.appendChild($point.get(0));
    this.markerLayer.append(fragment);
};
```

This overlay gets the map, a LatLng object and the URL of an icon. The good thing is that you can write your own HTML to the layer, the bad thing is that you have to handle all the stuff the Maps API does for you (like marker image anchor handling) by your own. The example only works good with 32x32px images where the anchor is in the middle of the image, so it's still pretty rough.

To use the CustomOverlay, just instantiate it like this:

```
// your map center / marker LatLng
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.247471, 89.920990);

// instantiate map
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    {zoom: 4, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
);  

// create the clusterer, but of course with markers
//var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, []);

// add custom overlay to map
var customCustomOverlay = new CustomOverlay(map, myLatlng, 'http://www.foo.bar/icon.png');
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Only would I change: `style="'+'width:1px; height:1px;'` and in img `style="position: absolute; top: -THE_HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE_HEREpx; left: -HALF_OF_THE_WIDTH_OF_IMAGE_HEREpx"` so the drawing (as it should be with classic pin marker) appears right on top of the place

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but didn't want to handle a new overlay.

Without having to create a specific Overlay, you can just switch the overlay's parent containers z-indexes.

This can be achieved by using the following function :

```
_changeOverlayOrder = function(map) {
    var panes = map.getPanes();
    var markerOverlayDiv = panes.overlayImage.parentNode;
    var clusterOverlayDiv = panes.overlayMouseTarget.parentNode;
    // Make the clusters clickable.
    if(!markerOverlayDiv.style.pointerEvents) {
        markerOverlayDiv.style.cssText += ";pointer-events: none;";
    }
    // Switch z-indexes
    if(markerOverlayDiv.style.zIndex < clusterOverlayDiv.style.zIndex) {
        var tmp = markerOverlayDiv.style.zIndex;
        markerOverlayDiv.style.zIndex = clusterOverlayDiv.style.zIndex;
        clusterOverlayDiv.style.zIndex = tmp;
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is "this" in this.getPanes()?

Comment: @mouwah's answer is almost correct, but there is no `getPanes()` method to a map object. You have to define your custom `OverlayView()` class to use `getPanes()` method and change `zIndex` of `overlayMouseTarget` pane.

Comment: This code *was* working perfectly until now, but **now google changed something and it suddenly stopped working!**

Comment: I have put a bounty on this question so if you adapt your answer to the new situation you can achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can override it with CSS.

CSS

```
.gm-style-pbc + div > div > div:first-child{ z-index: 108 !important; }
```

SCSS

```
.gm-style-pbc{
   + div{
     > div{
       >div{
         &:first-child{
            z-index: 108 !important;
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```